# Resize Tkinter widget and canvas when window resize?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, resize

i know this might sound like a similar question to some already asked question, but the problem that im having  is that i placed all widgets using .place(x=?,y=?) instead of using a tkinter grid like most questions, thats why im wondering if anyone have an idea to make it work without the need to rewrite everything using grid, here is an example from my code :

```
    #canvas
    self.fig.clear()
    self.fig=plt.figure()
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.16)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    self.CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
    plt.plot(pointX, pointY, 'kx')
    plt.clabel(self.CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.canvas.tkcanvas.place(x=0,y=350,hight=400,width=400)
    self.canvas.show()
    #Label
    label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Horizontal", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label1.place(x = 20, y = 50,height=20)
    label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Vertikal", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label2.place(x = 120, y = 50,height=20)
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There is a tkinter window resize event, and everytime that's triggered you could cycle through and adjust the size and position of every single widget. But doing that would be ridiculous. It would be far easier and far more efficient to just change your program to use `.pack()` or `.grid()`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer

Comment: Hey @EthanField is there a possibility to give me an example on how to use the window resize event, cause i tried using grid and so far it is not looking how it got to be using place, thank you.

Comment: I'll try and get an example working for you later on, watch this space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one of the options is to use relative positioning and size. For instance:

```
label1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.25, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.2)
```

This way, when You resize window, it should change widget size accordingly. However, as stated by @Ethan Field, it would be very painful to place all the widgets on the form using this method.

You can find more info [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#patterns).